# Python procedure that uses another procedure returns none

Tags: python, python-3.x

I very new with python and I'm doing an online class to learn the basics. While everything is going well, there are still a things that I don't seem to grasp in python..

Even though I found a much simpler way to solve the bellow problem, I'd still like to understand why my procedure is returning "None" .. Is it mistake with my if statements ? a syntax error ?

**Here is the problem:**

Define a procedure, union, that takes as inputs two lists.
It should modify the first input list to be the set union of the two lists. You may assume the first list is a set, that is, it contains no repeated elements.

The result we are expecting:

```
a = [1,2,3]
b = [2,4,6]

union(a,b)
print a 
#>>> [1,2,3,4,6]
```

You will note that, in my procedure, I'm using another procedure to find if a list item is in the other list. Could the problem be coming from that ?

**Here is my code:**

```
def find_element(a,b):
    if b in a:
        return a.index(b)
    return - 1



 def union(a,b):
        i = 0
        while i < len(b) - 1:
            c = find_element(a,b[i])

            if c != -1:
                i = i + 1 
            if c == -1:
                a = a.append(b[i])
                i = i + 1 
        return a

    a = [1,2,3]
    b = [2,4,6]

    print(union(a,b))
```

Comment: Problem is at `a = a.append(b[i])`. `append` method works in-place and returns None.

Comment: `list.append()` is an in-place operations. It modifies the list and returns `None`.

Comment: Thanks for your answers ! So that means It's impossible to set a variable equal to something that we modify why an in place operation (append, extend etc). 

Are there other cases where setting a variable won't work either and return "None" ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
a = a.append(b[i])
```

Here, a.append(b[i]) appends b[i] to a and returns 'none' which you have assigned to 'a'.

change this to

```
a.append(b[i])
```

and you should atleast get an output.

Comment: And no need to define any functions just convert the lists into sets and use union operator a.union(b)

Answer (score 0):

just in case you may need it.
you code could will be easier to read if you have it like this.
but its nice to challenge yourself. 
best,

```
def union(a, b):
    for item in b:
         if item not in a:
             a.append(item)
    return a

a = [1, 2, 3]
b = [2, 4, 6]
x = union(a, b)
print(x)
```

Comment: Thanks ! It's actually the solution which is provided in the course :)